# Adding multiple columns all at once

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and need help with some codes.

Can anyone help me to create a VBA code that can insert 4 multiple columns at the left of the first column and also 2 columns to the right of another particular column all at once with specific headers?

The first column having no header, the second one will be Portfolio Identifier, Report Date (MM/DD/YYYY) then lastly Security Identifier Type("CUSIP","SEDOL"). However, I am getting error message saying subscript out of range.

Simultaneously, I need to add 2 columns with no headers to the right of a particular column.

I know this sounds confusing but I hope you'll be able to understand.

Below is what I have for the mean time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 With Sheets("File Source").Columns(1).Resize(, 4)
    .Insert
    .Offset(, -4).Rows(1).Value = Array("", "Portfolio Identifier", "Report Date (MM/DD/YYYY)", "Security Identifier Type("CUSIP","SEDOL")")
    
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the Macro Recorder in the first instance and this will get you started. The take it one step at a time.

Comment: How do you identify the *"particular"* column? What is its title, letter, or number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insert Columns With Headers

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    
    Dim AfterTitles As Variant: AfterTitles = Array("Part1", "Part2")
    Dim BeforeTitles As Variant: BeforeTitles = Array( _
        "", "Portfolio Identifier", "Report Date (MM/DD/YYYY)", _
        "Security Identifier Type(""CUSIP"",""SEDOL"")")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("File Source")
    
    InsertIndexedWithTitles ws, 6, AfterTitles, True, True, True
    InsertIndexedWithTitles ws, 1, BeforeTitles, False, True, True
    
End Sub
```

**The Helper Procedure (Method)**

```vb
Sub InsertIndexedWithTitles( _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        ColumnIndex As Long, _
        ColumnTitles As Variant, _
        Optional InsertAfter As Boolean = False, _
        Optional BoldHeaders As Boolean = False, _
        Optional AutoFitColumns As Boolean = False)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(ColumnTitles) - LBound(ColumnTitles) + 1
    With ws.Cells(ColumnIndex)
        .Offset(, Abs(InsertAfter)).EntireColumn.Resize(, cCount).Insert
        With .Offset(, IIf(InsertAfter, 1, -cCount)).Resize(, cCount)
            .Value = ColumnTitles
            If BoldHeaders Then .Font.Bold = True
            If AutoFitColumns Then .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- When dealing with strings, ensure to use double quotation marks ("") for nested quotes or Chr(34).
- Altering the range object within a `With` clause simplifies the code.
- If you insert two Cols first, then it is easy to get the column F `(referencing to the column before any changes)`. And it doesn't bother the next cols insertion

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()

    '  Add 2 columns to the right of column F
    Sheets(1).Range("G1").Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
    Sheets(1).Range("G1").Resize(, 2).Value = Array("New1", "New2")
    
    ' insert 4 multiple columns at the left of the first col
    With Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(, 4)
        .EntireColumn.Insert
        .Offset(, -4).Value = Array("", "Portfolio Identifier", "Report Date (MM/DD/YYYY)", "Security Identifier Type(""CUSIP"",""SEDOL"")")
    End With
    
    ' set bold on header
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wanna know if I can add 2 columns to the right of a certain column to be executed at the same time in the above? Like for example 2 columns to the right of column F (referencing to the column before any changes)? Also I want these headers to be in Bold format like the other headers. Thankk you in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much your help on this! Wish I could learn creating vba codes too!